# Geckodriver, Firefox and Centos compatibitly

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, automation, centos, geckodriver

What is a good way to solve the problem of incompatible versions of ***geckodriver***, ***firefox*** and ***OS***.

I am my local desktop which has ***Firefox Quantum(64)***, ***mac OS*** and ***Geckodriver v0.23.0***.

My pytest/selenium automation runs fine.

Now I want to run the same code on my ***linux CentOS*** which has ***Firefox 52.7.3 version***. I tried installing the latest FF but its not allowing me to.

When I run my automation code on linux it does not work because the geckodriver is not compatible with the old firefox.

***Is there a way to run my automation with latest geckodriver on my linux CentOS*** ?

Comment: Why couldn't you upgrade firefox on CentOS?

Comment: I tried but it says you already have the latest firefox version 52. Maybe a corporate policy.

Comment: "I tried installing the latest FF but its not allowing me to." - what's the error/print when you tried to upgrade it?